# Como saber si en una cadena contiene emojis JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Hola actualmente tengo un ejercio y es que teniendo una cadena de caracteres deseo saber si hay y cuantos emojis hay en esta.

Comment: Bienvenido, por favor lee [ask], edita y coloca lo que llevas al momento

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad.

Comment: Preguntas solicitando ayuda con trabajo escolar deben incluir un resumen del trabajo que has realizado hasta el momento para resolver el problema y una descripción de la dificultad que estás teniendo para resolverlo. Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información, y edita la pregunta con las recomendaciones que encontrarás allí.

Answer (score 3):

Aquí hay una libreria [emoji-regex](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/emoji-regex).

También podrias hacerlo directamente con expresiones regulares

Aquí te dejo esta que es muy completa:

```
(?:[\u2700-\u27bf]|(?:\ud83c[\udde6-\uddff]){2}|[\ud800-\udbff][\udc00-\udfff])[\ufe0e\ufe0f]?(?:[\u0300-\u036f\ufe20-\ufe23\u20d0-\u20f0]|\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff])?(?:\u200d(?:[^\ud800-\udfff]|(?:\ud83c[\udde6-\uddff]){2}|[\ud800-\udbff][\udc00-\udfff])[\ufe0e\ufe0f]?(?:[\u0300-\u036f\ufe20-\ufe23\u20d0-\u20f0]|\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff])?)*
```

Fuente: https://thekevinscott.com/emojis-in-javascript/

Comment: se te agradece la intención de ayuda, pero hasta que el OP no indique exactamente cual es su código, que lleva hecho y que dudas tiene, este tipo de preguntas no se deben responder

Comment: Esta bien, soy nuevo aquí.

Comment: Que afán de calificar como mala la respuesta si cumple con lo que el OP está preguntando. ¿No te das cuenta que ambos son nuevos @anonimo? Eso solo incita a que ya no pregunten o respondan. Excelente el comentario, pero que se quede ahí.

Comment: Bienvenido @FrancoSalcedo a Stack Overflow en español, aunque tú perfil demuestra que tienes mas de un año, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Cómo escribo una buena respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) en especial el punto: ***Contesta preguntas bien formadas*** y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad.

Comment: Es una cuenta creada pero inactiva por lo visto. Yo dejé de actualizarme en CCNA hace 6 años, aunque esté registrado en Cisco... Sólo digo que, no hay que ponernos el pie nosotros mismos.

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos, si mi cuenta es antigua pero recupere mi contraseña después de mucho. Ahora quiero aportar y preguntar también. haré el recorrido y leeré los enlaces que me sugirieron. Muchas gracias!